# Using django to download image to localhost from html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, django, server

I am having difficulty trying to download an image from HTML to my localhost

```
    {% extends "social/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class='main'>
{% if text %}
<h3>Your Profile</h3>
{{ text }} <br style='clear:left;'><br>
{% endif %}
Image : <br>

<form action="img_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 

 </form>



<form method='POST' action='/social/editProfile/' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <textarea name='text' cols='30' rows='3'>{{ text }}</textarea>
    <br>
    <h3>Address</h3>
    <textarea name='address' cols='30' rows='3'>{{ text }}</textarea>
    <br>
    <h3>workplace</h3>
    <textarea name='workplace' cols='30' rows='3'>{{ text }}</textarea>
    <br>
    <h3>telephone</h3>
    <textarea name='telephone' cols='30' rows='3'>{{ text }}</textarea>
    <br>

   <input type='submit' value='Save Profile' name = "submit" value = "submit">
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my HTML form, I am able to make the user upload an image from their local directory. When the user clicks submit it sends all the information for name, address, workplace and telephone to a database. However, I also want the image they chose to be downloaded to the local directory when submit is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I almost forgot, I created an entire website where I discuss this along with everything else you would ever need to know about uploading and downloading files. See http://mrme.me/lio/blog/. I created a website and chrome app called LIO (which I still need to finish). But I experienced some big pain points in getting a stylized working upload and download system for the images that would be uploaded to this app. So I decided to share what I learned in the process and created a blog about my experiences creating the LIO App.

See also [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

because of security measures you have no control over where the file is being saved, however, there is some control with chrome apps; i discuss that in my blog. So the best way of going about this is to download the file like so.

```
let the_pic = "data:image/png;base64,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"

var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = the_pic;

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();

window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
a.remove();
```

Comment: I want the user to be able to upload an image to the html form and then when they press submit the form will download that picture again to the local directory, whereas the example lets the user download a specific image.

Comment: I'd just realized that and was about to update my answer. It's updated now. Does that help out a little more. I've done this before, and I can dig through the code I use if you need more info than this.

Comment: I just remembered I have a little blog about this. See http://mrme.me/lio/blog/ Also take a look at the JS on this page http://mrme.me/lio/blog/demos/basic-example.html It's a simple example of me uploading, compressing, and downloading a picture. You will also find on that blog a cool method of styling the upload button .